# value for expression in textrun .... end of statement expected

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, fetchxml

When trying to preview my report I'm getting the following error:

[image]

The formula that I am using is:

```
=String.Format(New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(1033), chrw(123)&amp;"0"&amp;chrw(125)&amp;" "&amp;chrw(40)&amp;"Count"&amp;chrw(58)&amp;" "&amp;chrw(123)&amp;"1"&amp;chrw(125)&amp;chrw(41), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!stepname.Value), "Not specified", Fields!stepname.Value), CInt(Count("")).ToString("###,###,###,##0;-###,###,###,##0;0"), Code.GetCultureInfo()))
```

This expression is lodged within the textruns xml field:

```
                  <TextRuns>
                    <TextRun>
                      <Value>the expression is here</Value>
                      <Style>
                        <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                        <FontSize>7pt</FontSize>
                        <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                        <Color>#ffffff</Color>
                      </Style>
                    </TextRun>
                  </TextRuns>
```

A previous version of this formula worked fine (and still does):

```
=String.Format(New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(1033), chrw(123)&amp;"0"&amp;chrw(125)&amp;" "&amp;chrw(40)&amp;"Count"&amp;chrw(58)&amp;" "&amp;chrw(123)&amp;"1"&amp;chrw(125)&amp;chrw(41), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!stepname.Value), "Not specified", Fields!stepname.Value), CInt(Count("")).ToString(First(Fields!NumberFormat_0_Precision.Value, "DSNumberAndCurrencyInfo"), Code.GetCultureInfo()))
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
=String.Format(
    New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(1033), 
    chrw(123)&amp;"0"&amp;chrw(125)&amp;" "&amp;chrw(40)&amp;"Count"&amp;chrw(58)&amp;" "&amp;chrw(123)&amp;"1"&amp;chrw(125)&amp;chrw(41), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!stepname.Value), "Not specified", Fields!stepname.Value), 
    CInt(Count("")).ToString("###,###,###,##0;-###,###,###,##0;0"), 
    Code.GetCultureInfo())
```

Seems you've had one bracket too much in the end

Comment: thank you so much. i'll accept your answer in 9 minutes

Comment: no problem - I'm really glad it helped - I also had the same problems while developing reporting services reports :) Regards.

Comment: if you have a chance do you know a reason for the report showing NO DATA in crm online whereas showing plenty of data within VIsual Studio?

Comment: Hi. Does Crm online means Crystal Reports website with reports?

Comment: Sadly don't know almost anything about CRM Dynamics :) - my colleague only dought quite deep into it but he used MSRS reports as far as I know, however, maybe I'll be able to ask him for that problem.